# How to write Gherkin scenarios when there are multiple validations for a given state

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am new to cucumber - Gherkin world. I am trying to write a feature file. I am planning to test a web page that is static with lot of static content(lets say  100 sections) that I need to verify.
Ideally if I start writing based on my understanding of gherkin, it looks as below:

Scenario:test engagement page content

Given I am an user with >10000 balance

When I land on my engagement page

Then section1 should be displayed correctly

And section2 should be displayed correctly

And section3 should be displayed correctly

And section4 should be displayed correctly

--and so on -----

And section100 should be displayed correctly.

This definitely is looking ugly. How can I break this into multiple scenarios.
I am testing everything once I am on that page. I am not doing any activity on the page. Once I land, I just need to verify all sections.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can do this, but a Scenario Outline is likely your best option assuming the sections share elements and assertions.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify the display of all sections on the Engagement Page
Given I am a user with >10000 balance
When I land of Engagement Page
Then the header of <section> should read "<headerText>"
And the icon of <section> should be displayed
And the body of <section> should read "<bodyText>"

Examples:
  | section   | headerText         | bodyText        |
  | Section 1 | This is Header #1  | This is Body #1 |
  | Section 2 | Header Text of #2  | Body Text of #2 |
... etc
```

If the sections are unique in structure, you're faced with writing a scenario (or more, depending on your style - I don't personally like having multiple assertions in a single case) for each:

Say, for example, `section1` has a header, icon, and body text, you would end up with the following three scenarios:

```
Scenario: Verify display of header in Section 1
Given I am a user with >10000 balance
When I land of Engagement Page
Then the header of Section 1 should read "text"

Scenario: Verify display of icon in Section 1
Given I am a user with >10000 balance
When I land of Engagement Page
Then the icon of Section 1 should be displayed

Scenario: Verify display of body text in Section 1
Given I am a user with >10000 balance
When I land of Engagement Page
Then the body of Section 1 should read "text"
```

And if you're fine with multiple assertions per test:

```
Scenario: Verify display of Section 1
Given I am a user with >10000 balance
When I land of Engagement Page
Then the header of Section 1 should read "text"
And the icon of Section 1 should be displayed
And the body of Section 1 should read "text"
```

Comment: I wanted to do with second example that you mentioned.  But my question basically is all the verifications are when the user lands on that page .so when I implement in second example way , the given and when implementations starting from second scenario going to have no code at all because the user is already on that page.  Is it ok to have those given and when step implementations with literally no code

Comment: You'd then have test dependencies, which is a major no-no.

You probably want to then look into using a Background (it's a Gherkin keyword - Google its use) that includes the repeated steps and code that detects if you're already in that given "set up" state prior to doing anything and skips the rest of the step code if so.